# spark thrift server issue: Length field is empty for varchar fields

Tags: apache-spark, sas, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to read Data from Spark Thrift Server using SAS. In the table definition through DBeaver, I am seeing that **Length** field is empty only for fields with **VARCHAR** data type. I can see the length in the Data Type field as **varchar(32)**. But that doesn't suffice my purpose as the SAS application taps into the Length field. Since, this field is not populated now, SAS is defaulting to the max size and as a result its becoming extremely slow. I get the length field populated in Hive.

Comment: Do you have a reasonable "max" size?  If so, SAS can set a maximum "default" size to whatever that is - DBMAXTEXT - so if your char fields are typically 32 or less, you could set that perhaps?

Comment: Hi @Joe , thanks for your response. We have high degree of variability in terms of size. So, won’t be able to use db_max_text feature. Also tried setting size with the tag SASFMT on hive table. But SAS is not able to recognize it.